# youtube-dl - Where does one locate user-created functions ( )?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl, functions

I'm looking for clarification about an aspect of this question:

[Downloading videos to an external drive with youtube-dl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266568/downloading-videos-to-an-external-drive-with-youtube-dl)

[DannyRe's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/383085/527764) is great except that I may not be the only one wondering where to put such functions()? Should it go in the youtube-dl config file created as per a previous answer? Or where elsewhere?

Comment: Such functions are usually intended for the .bashrc file. In other words, append a function to .bashrc, and then reload it with `source .bashrc`.

Comment: You can find the answer here: [Where can I put a user-defined shell function?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344557/where-can-i-put-a-user-defined-shell-function)

Comment: The link to the answer(s) was extremely helpful and educational, especially. Many thanks